# String literal in SQL query field

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'd like to do a stuff command in string literal query and it give some error

The query without string literal working:

```
 SELECT apGr.*, 'Name: ' + apGr.GroupDesc + ' | Group: ' + apGr.GroupName GroupFull , 
 abc = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + appGrMn.Email
        FROM APP_GroupManager As appGrMn
        -- You only want to combine rows for a single ID here:
        WHERE appGrMn.GroupId = apGr.GroupId
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
, 1, 1, '')
FROM App_Group apGr 
WHERE apGr.GroupId = 239
```

The query as string literal failed:

```
    DECLARE @WhereQuery NVARCHAR(200) = ''
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(500)

    SET @GroupId = 5

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF(@GroupId IS NOT NULL)
      BEGIN
           PRINT(@GroupId)
           SET @WhereQuery = 'WHERE apGr.GroupId = ' + @GroupId 
      END
    ELSE IF (@SystemId IS NOT NULL)
      BEGIN
           SET @WhereQuery = 'WHERE apGr.SystemId = ' + @SystemId
      END
    ELSE IF (@GroupName IS NOT NULL)
      BEGIN
           SET @WhereQuery = 'WHERE apGr.GroupName = ''' + @GroupName + ''''
      END

   SET @Query = 'SELECT ''Name: '' + apGr.GroupDesc + '' | Group: '' + apGr.GroupName GroupFull  , 
 abc = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT '','' + appGrMn.AdministratorMail
        FROM APP_GroupManager As appGrMn
        -- You only want to combine rows for a single ID here:
        WHERE appGrMn.GroupId = apGr.GroupId
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE
    ).value(''.'', varchar(max))
, 1, 1, '') ' + 
                'FROM App_Group apGr '  + 
                'JOIN T_SensitiveLevel AS tSen ON tSen.SensitiveLevelId = apGr.SensitiveLevelId '  + @WhereQuery
                PRINT @Query
   EXEC(@Query)
END
```

The printed query looks:

```
5
SELECT 'Name: ' + apGr.GroupDesc + ' | Group: ' + apGr.GroupName GroupFull  , 
 abc = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT ',' + appGrMn.AdministratorMail
        FROM APP_GroupManager As appGrMn
        -- You only want to combine rows for a single ID here:
        WHERE appGrMn.GroupId = apGr.GroupId
        FOR XML PATH ('), TYPE
    ).value('.', varchar(max))
, 1, 1, ') FROM App_Group apGr JOIN T_SensitiveLevel AS tSen ON tSen.SensitiveLevelId = apGr.SensitiveLevelId WHERE apGr.GroupId = 2
```

It not append the `@WhereQuery` as it should and the error is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: In that second query in your question, `FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE` should be `FOR XML PATH (''''), TYPE`. The same for the last argument line of the STUFF call: `, 1, 1, '')` should be `, 1, 1, '''')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some '' related syntax error. instead of '' you need to use '''' when expecting ('') in output. Where clause is truncated since @query became larger then it's length(500). I have made some changes in the query please check:

```
DECLARE @WhereQuery NVARCHAR(200) = ''
    DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(2000)
    declare @GroupId NVARCHAR(500)
    declare @SystemId NVARCHAR(500)
    declare @GroupName NVARCHAR(500)
    
    set @GroupName='a'

    SET @GroupId = 5

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF(@GroupId IS NOT NULL)
      BEGIN
           PRINT(@GroupId)
           SET @WhereQuery = 'WHERE apGr.GroupId = ' + @GroupId 
      END
    ELSE IF (@SystemId IS NOT NULL)
      BEGIN
           SET @WhereQuery = 'WHERE apGr.SystemId = ' + @SystemId
      END
    ELSE IF (@GroupName IS NOT NULL)
      BEGIN
           SET @WhereQuery = 'WHERE apGr.GroupName = ''' + @GroupName + ''''
      END
    
   SET @Query = 'SELECT ''Name: '' + apGr.GroupDesc + '' | Group: '' + apGr.GroupName GroupFull  , 
 abc = STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT '','' + appGrMn.AdministratorMail
        FROM APP_GroupManager As appGrMn
        -- You only want to combine rows for a single ID here:
        WHERE appGrMn.GroupId = apGr.GroupId
        FOR XML PATH (''''), TYPE
    ).value(''.'', ''varchar(max)'')
, 1, 1, '''') ' + 
                'FROM App_Group apGr '  + 
                'JOIN T_SensitiveLevel AS tSen ON tSen.SensitiveLevelId = apGr.SensitiveLevelId '  + @WhereQuery +''
                PRINT @Query
                
   EXEC(@Query)
```

Comment: You saved me
Thank you!